# How to call this angular function on load

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I am having a async function `getDataStandard()` which needs to be executed on click.I need to get the function automatically done without clicking. How to do that. Please help me as I am new to ionic.

```
async getDataStandard() {
    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
    await loading.present();

    this.http.get('https://www.labourguide.co.za/LabourguideApi/index.php?q=mostRecentPublications').pipe(
      finalize(() => loading.dismiss())
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
console.log("Testing ...............1");
      this.data = data;
console.log(data);
console.log("Testing ..............2");
    }, err => {
      console.log('JS Call error: ', err);
    });
  }
```

This is the ionic part

```
 <ion-button expand="block" (click)="getDataStandard()">getDataStandard</ion-button>
```

Comment: Just execute it once the component is loaded. Showing som code would help giving you the desired solution, though.

Comment: you can use ngOnInit for the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call it on your `ngOnInit`

```
export class App implements OnInit{
  constructor(){
     //called first time before the ngOnInit()
  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.getDataStandard() ;

  }
}
```

Comment: @Adberrahum Soubai Elidrissi Thank you

Comment: Welcome please consider one of the answers as accepted to close your question, regards

Comment: how to activate this function without using <ion-button> tag

Comment: This function (ngOnInit) is called automatically when your component (page) is loaded

Comment: can i call this before the view loads the list

Comment: Yes but it can block the load of your component until it finishes. if you want this behavior call it in `constructor`

Comment: @Adberrahim I tried what you said but my list is not loading without double clicking the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195178/discussion-between-abderrahim-soubai-elidrissi-and-sobha).

Answer (score 3):

You can call this function from `ngOnInit(){}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `getDataStandard()` in `ngOnInit()`.

```ts
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.getDataStandard();
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

angular has several lifecycle hooks they are just an method of the component that manage and run by angualr,there are three method that sutable for your need ngOninit ,ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit .

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getDataStandard();  
} 

ngAfterContentInit() {}

ngAfterViewInit() {}
```

> all previes method will run once in sequence so if you want the function
>   will run as soon is possibe use ngOninit,or it you want to run after
>   the component fully initialized I will choses ngAfterViewInit.

[Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence)